# Symfony2 DomCrawler each Loop, will not add new StdClass object to object outside the loop

Tags: php, symfony, dom, laravel

```
    use Goutte\Client;

    $results = new StdClass;

    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
    $crawler->filter('.div')->each(function ($node) 
    {
        $item = new StdClass;
        $item->test = 'hello';

        $results->data[] = $item;
    });

    var_dump($results);
```

The output of `var_dump($results)` is always a totally empty object:

```
object(stdClass)[176]
```

The URL is correct and the filter is correct, the class is working, but if I make use of `$node` and pull text form the HTML it works within the loop, but the data is not saved within it to the `$results` Object.

As in the example above, the text 'hello' in the `$item` class is not even present in the final `$results` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow the anonymous function to access local variable, btw I don't see that you are using `$node` inside your closure

```
function ($node) use ($results)
{
    $item = new StdClass;
    $item->test = 'hello';

    $results->data[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, I still get back an empty object. :(

Comment: @Ezra, please check that closure is being called

Comment: My bad, this DOES work, however I changed the crawl filter for this example and forgot to change it back when I tested your answer. Therefore no class of '.div' existed in the DOM and no loops ran. Your answer works perfectly once the correct filter was used. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You may try this:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$results = $crawler->filter('.div')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
    return $node->text();
});
var_dump($results);
```

Check the reference on [Symfony website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Docs! I couldn't find them for this component on their website oddly enough. :)

Comment: I just had a similar problem - this solution worked for me!